# Django No Post matches the given query?

Tags: python, django

A bit of magic : today i was woken up, power my laptop and start working for my project, but...
When i pushed on button, django was return to me 404 error, and say "that No match queries". It a bit sad me, because yesterday all was work as well as never.

This is my huge view:

```
def p(request, pk):
    user = request.user
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, pk=pk)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    comment = Comments.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    who_come = WhoComeOnEvent.objects.filter(which_event=topic.id)

    if request.is_ajax() and request.POST.get('action') == 'joinEvent':
        who_come_obj = WhoComeOnEvent.objects.create(
            visiter=user,
            which_event=post.topic
        )

        visitors_usernames = []
        for w in who_come:
            visitors_usernames.append(w.visiter.username)

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(visitors_usernames))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomCommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.creator = user
            comment = Comments.objects.create(
                body=form.cleaned_data.get('body'),
                creator=user,
                post=post
            )

            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

    else:
        form = CustomCommentForm()
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': post, 'topic': topic, 'comment': comment,
                                     'form': form, 'who_come': who_come})
```

the problem in `post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)`, this code worked for month but now it shows 404 error. I don't know what the reason. Why it broken? 
I try to change `post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)` to `Post.objects.filter(topic=topic.id)`, now it looks fine, after changing i can push on button and go forward by url. But if i want make comment it return Error to me `Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Post: sfdfhgf>]>": "Comments.post" must be a "Post" instance.` on line `comment.post = post`. Here i'm in stuck.

In database all exists.

Here is my model

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='topics')
    starter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='topics')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject


class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='posts')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='+')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.topic.subject


class Comments(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comment')
    body = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comment')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s comment on %s' % (self.body, self.post.topic.subject)
```

Have no idea why it broken:(

#### Solution :

It look very weird, but solution was in database. I deleted used database, created new one and all works as it must. Any idea what was wrong with database?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use the same pk for three models `topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, pk=pk)`, `post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)`, `comment = Comments.objects.filter(pk=pk)`. Which model is `pk` meant to be the primary key for? If `get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)` has started failing, then you need to show the view/template that created the link that gives you a 404.

Comment: In your first code block: indentation is part of the code in Python.

Comment: Recreating the database might have stopped the error, but the code is still incorrect. As I said before, `pk` should be the primary key of an object for one model. It doesn't make sense to use that pk to query three different models.

Comment: @Alasdair yes, thank you, i'll fix it.